# What's the best way to maintain Fortresses

Tags: endless-legend, endless-legend-tempest

Fortreses are vital in Tempest. 
So if you complete a parlay quest which grants control of the fortress, you hold control until you are defeated in battle at the fortress. Usually it isn't very long until Fomorians attack, so an ungarrisoned fortress does not last. Having many fortresses could require garrisoned navies in all, which is seemingly expensive in dust and production. Generally my only conflict is with roaming navies, so these forces seem excessive. 
How should I manage this, in subquestions:

1. If I control all fortresses in an ocean region, are the Fomorians pacified, and thus the fortresses will not need a garrison?
2. Is a player attack on a garrison an act of war, or is it possible in Cold War. Does this change with Black Spot?
3. Given that losing units to roaming armies is expensive, as they will eventully need replacement, what is the minimal/optimal garrison size, so as not to lo see units during an attack?
4. Is there a maximum size to Fomorian navies? I have only seen at most three per stack, however I have seen multiple stacks attack simultaneously. Should I then have units stationed outside the fortress, just in case?
5. When a fortress is under attack, is it better to have units avoid engagement, to wait out the six turns of the battle phase, or should I aim to destroy the roaming navy?
6. Should I just accept losing fortresses, and having to reclaim them?

Comment: No link for this (which is why it's a comment, even if it is a partial answer), but I believe the answer to #1 is that the Formorians are pacified, and you don't need a garrison... except from other player/AI factions.  #2 seems to count as war if you have the region; not war if you don't.  Not sure on the rest.